# concatenate multi values in one record without duplication

Tags: python, vba

I have a dbf table like below which is the result of one to many join from two tables. I want to have unique zone values from one Taxlot id field.

table name: input table
tid ----- zone
1 ------ A
1 ------ A
1 ------ B
1 ------ C
2 ------ D
2 ------ E
3 ------ C

Desirable output table
table name: input table
tid ----- zone
1 ------ A, B, C
2 ------ D, E
3 ------ C

I got some help but couldn't make it to work.

```
inputTbl = r"C:\temp\input.dbf"
taxIdZoningDict = {}
searchRows = gp.searchcursor(inputTbl)
searchRow = searchRows.next()
while searchRow:
   if searchRow.TID in taxIdZoningDict:
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID].add(searchRow.ZONE)
   else:
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID] = set() #a set prevents dulpicates!
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID].add(searchRow.ZONE)
   searchRow = searchRows.next()

outputTbl = r"C:\temp\output.dbf"
gp.CreateTable_management(r"C:\temp", "output.dbf")
gp.AddField_management(outputTbl, "TID", "LONG")
gp.AddField_management(outputTbl, "ZONES", "TEXT", "", "", "20")
tidList = taxIdZoningDict.keys()
tidList.sort() #sorts in ascending order
insertRows = gp.insertcursor(outputTbl)
for tid in tidList:
   concatString = ""
   for zone in taxIdZoningDict[tid]
      concatString = concatString + zone + ","
   insertRow = insertRows.newrow()
   insertRow.TID = tid
   insertRow.ZONES = concatString[:-1]
   insertRows.insertrow(insertRow)
del insertRow
del insertRows
```

Comment: This is tagged 'python' and 'vba', yet all the code answers are in Python. I can easily provide a vba example to do this. Can you clarify if the solution is meant to be in either language, or if it is mis-tagged?

Comment: @transistor1, go ahead and provide the vba solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [my dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) and `defaultdict` to greatly simplify that code:

```
import dbf
from collections import defaltdict

inputTbl = dbf.Table(r'c:\temp\input.dbf')
taxIdZoning = defaultdict(set)

for record in inputTbl:
    taxIdZoning[record.tid].add(record.zone)
inputTbl.close()

outputTbl = dbf.Table(r'c:\temp\output.dbf', 'tid N(17.0), zones C(20)')
for tid in sorted(taxIdZoning):
    record = outputTbl.append()
    record.tid = tid
    record.zones = ','.join(sorted(taxIdZoning[tid]))
outputTbl.close()
```

NOTE: field names are lowercase, and I wasn't sure exactly how to represent LONG, but hopefully 17 digits is enough. :)  My apologies for any bugs -- hard to test without input files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me using both Microsoft Access VBA and Microsoft Excel VBA. It isn't very efficient code, but it works. I was able to open the resultant file in both Access and Excel.

Set the `sDBF*` and `sOutDBF*` variables to tailor this to your own custom paths.

```
Sub VBASolution()
    Dim oRS
    Dim sConn
    Dim sDBFPath, sOutDBFPath
    Dim sDBFName, sOutDBFName
    Dim oDict
    Dim curTID, curZone, sZones
    Dim oConn
    Dim oFS
    Dim sTableName

    sDBFPath = "C:\Path\To\DBFs\"
    sDBFName = "Input.dbf"

    sOutDBFPath = "C:\Path\To\DBFs\"
    sOutDBFName = "RESULTS.dbf"

    sConn = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)}; DriverID=277; Dbq="
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


    oRS.Open "SELECT DISTINCT tid, zone FROM " & sDBFName, sConn & sDBFPath

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do While Not oRS.EOF
        curTID = oRS.Fields("tid").Value
        curZone = oRS.Fields("zone").Value
        If Not oDict.Exists(curTID) Then
            oDict.Add curTID, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        If Not oDict(curTID).Exists(curZone) Then
            oDict(curTID).Add curZone, curZone
        End If
        oRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    oRS.Close

    Set oRS = Nothing

    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open sConn & sOutDBFPath

    'Delete the resultant DBF file if it already exists.
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With oFS
        If .FileExists(sOutDBFPath & "\" & sOutDBFName) Then
            .DeleteFile sOutDBFPath & "\" & sOutDBFName
        End If
    End With

    sTableName = oFS.GetBaseName(sOutDBFName)

    oConn.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & sTableName & " (tid int, zone varchar(80))"

    Dim i, j
    For Each i In oDict.Keys
        curTID = i
        sZones = ""
        For Each j In oDict(i)
            sZones = sZones & "," & j
        Next
        sZones = Mid(sZones, 2)
        oConn.Execute "INSERT INTO " & sTableName & " (tid, zone) VALUES ('" & curTID & "','" & sZones & "')"
    Next
    oConn.Close

    Set oConn = Nothing
    Set oDict = Nothing
    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT: For what it's worth, this also worked for me by inserting it into a VBScript .VBS file (text) in Windows XP and adding this line to the bottom of the file:

`Call VBASolution()`

I do not know whether or not it requires Office to be installed or if the appropriate dbf drivers come with Windows.

Comment: LOL I'm inclined to agree with you. Thanks for the bounty - I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think Morlock's answer does not satisfy the requirement of dropping duplicates. I would use a defaultdict(set), which will automatically omit dups, instead of defaultdict(list), and thus .add() instead of .append().

Comment: It did :) But it got lost in the edits. I added a line 'v = list(set(v)) to fix that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
taxIdZoningDict = {}
searchRows = gp.searchcursor(inputTbl)
searchRow = searchRows.next()
while searchRow:
   if searchRow.TID in taxIdZoningDict:
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID].add(searchRow.ZONE)
   else:
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID] = set() #a set prevents dulpicates!
      taxIdZoningDict[searchRow.TID].add(searchRow.ZONE)
   searchRow = searchRows.next()
```

do this:

```
zones = {}
for row in gp.searchcursor(inputTbl):
    zones.setdefault(row.TID, set())
    zones[row.TID].add(row.ZONE)
```

much more pythonic, with the same result ;-)

And then to output:

```
for k, v in zones:
    print k, ", ".join(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quickly made code in Python that may suit your needs, with minimal fidgeting.

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("input_file.txt") as f:   
    for line in f:
        parsed = line.strip().split()
        print parsed
        k = parsed[0]
        v = parsed[2]
        d[k].append(v)

for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    s = " ----- "
    v = list(set(v)) # Must be a library function to do this
    v.sort()
    print k, s,
    for j in v:
        print j,
    print
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Use `collections.defaultdict` and save a bit of mess. `d=defaultdict(list)` and the last three lines of the loop simplify to `d[k].append( v )`

Comment: Also, use `for k in d: v= items[k]` in the second loop to make it a hair simpler and more pythonic.

Comment: Note, when working with files: 1) **Always** use a context manager, that is to say `with open("input_file.txt") as f:` to ensure that the file gets closed no matter what and 2) Never use `for line in f.readlines():`, which is wasteful. Use `for line in f:`. (Similarly, you can loop over a dict's items with `for k, v in d.iteritems()`, using `iteritems` to avoid making a needless list.) Also, `some_string.split(" ")` is typically spelled `some_string.split()`.

Comment: @Mike Graham Thank you. This is great input. I'll be sure to implement this starting right now in the Python code I am doing this afternoon. Cheers

Comment: @S.Lott I'm currently working. If you have time, be our guest :)  I'll also get a chance to see how exactly you use 'collection.defaultdict'. Cheers

Comment: I edited in these things and additionally change the loop to be over `sorted(d.iteritems())` so that the order of the results would be the expected order. Note that this makes the solution O(n log n) and that there are plenty of O(n) solutions available.

Comment: Good code for generic use, but it will not work with dbf files.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wanted commas in the zone column.  Might change the output piece of Morlock's code slightly to get those commas and *perhaps* be a little clearer by using this single line for the output instead of an explicit loop over `v`:

```
    print k, s, ",".join(v)
```

That does pack more into one line (possibly a negative).  The use of `join` in this way is pretty common in python, and IMHO expresses the intent more clearly (and is easier to digest when reading) than the explicit loop.